# Contact Form 7: custom validation

Tags: plugins, php, functions, plugin-contact-form-7, validation

I'm currently using the Contact Form 7 plugin, which is great and works perfectly, but what I'm now trying to achieve with it is some custom validation rules.
I found this extension: http://code-tricks.com/contact-form-7-custom-validation-in-wordpress/ that once added to `functions.php` adds a whole raft of extra validation rules.
For example:

```
$acceptNumbers = array('acceptNumber', 'acceptNumber1', 'acceptNumber2', 'acceptNumber3', 'acceptNumber4', 'acceptNumber5', 'acceptNumber6');

foreach($acceptNumbers as $acceptNumber){
    if($name == $acceptNumber) {
        $acceptNum = $_POST[$acceptNumber];

        if($acceptNum != '') {
            if(ctype_digit($acceptNum)) {
                $result['valid'] = true;
            } else {
                $result['valid'] = false;
                $result['reason'][$name] = 'Please Enter Only Numbers';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Called in the short code like so: `[text* acceptNumber]` but what I want to validate is quite specific and I'm not sure how it'll be achieved. I'll have 1 text field, I want it to contain ONLY one word, anything more than one word won't be accepted, and this one word MUST begin with the letter `s`. I'm not even sure if this is at all achievable, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I did get it right:

```
<?php

function specialValidation($value) {
    $explode = explode(' ', $value);
    if(sizeof($explode) > 1) {
        echo 'ERROR: You have input more than one word.';
        return;
    }
    $mustBeS = substr($explode[0],0,1);
    if($mustBeS != 's' && $mustBeS != 'S') {
        echo 'ERROR: Your word must start with an "s" or "S".';
        return;
    }
}
```